# PHP/Ajax/HTML/SSH - I do not understand why it does not work

Tags: php, ajax, ssh, html-table

I cannot understand where the problem comes from. If someone has an idea :( I have to download a file from a ssh server, but the file switch according to what the user is seeking. I have a PHP file for the ssh connection and download. I'm using ajax because I have to send the file location.

Let's see the code :

HTML :

```
       <?php if ( !is_null($this->listdepotdrpadmin) ) { ?>
            <table id="supervisionResDepotDrp">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="center">EVT_ID</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_DT</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_NOMFIC</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_STATUT</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_TEXTE</th>
                        <th class="center">DOWNLOAD</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <!-- Le 7ème champ statut_depot n'est pas affiché, car il sert uniquement pour les RG
                      Il est redondantt avec le 6ème qui est sa traduction en langage humain -->
                      <?php foreach ($this->listdepotdrpadmin as $elem) :?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="center"><?php print_r($elem['evt_id'])?></td>
                            <td class="center"><?php print_r($elem['evt_dt'])?></td>
                            <td id="afficher" class="center"><?php print_r($elem['evt_nomfic'])?></td>
                            <td class="center"><?php print_r($elem['evt_statut'])?></td>
                            <td class="center"><?php print_r($elem['evt_texte'])?></td>                
                            <!-- Si le champs evt_statut est remplis, affiche l'icone de telechargement -->  
                            <td class="center">
                                <?php if (isset($elem['evt_nomfic'])) : ?> 
                                    <img class='img-download' src='/img/download.png' id="js-download-file">
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <span id="spnText"></span>
                       <?php endforeach; ?> 
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          <?php } ?>
```

PHP file :

```
public function ajaxdownloadfileAction() {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        $this->view->lib = $this->_labelsFile;

        $connection = ssh2_connect($this->_configFile->ftp->hostname, $this->_configFile->ftp->port);
        if ($connection) {
            $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->_configFile->ftp->login, $this->_configFile->ftp->password);
            if ($login) {
                $content = true;
                if ($content) {
                    $fileName = $this->_getParam('fileName');  
                    $local = ' C:\Users\nboulein\Desktop\test\ ';
                    ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$fileName,$local);

            }
            $connection = null; unset($connection);
        }
     }

     $result['status'] = 'OK';
     $result['message'] = 'LE ficheir a bien ete telecharger';

     echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Ajax file :

```
// Gestion du bouton de téléchargement du fichier
$('#resultatsRecherche').on('click','#js-download-file',function(){
    $('#js-download-file').css("cursor","pointer" );
    var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var fileName = currow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    alert(fileName);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/supervision/admin/ajaxdownloadfile',
        async : true,
        data : {
            fileName : fileName
        },
        success : function(result) {
           var vResult = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
           if(vResult.status == 'OK'){
               alert(vResult.message);
           }
        }  
    });
});
```

On my webpage nothing is happening and when I open the console there is this:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function at HTMLDocument.
>       <anonymous> (admin.js:224) at Object.resolveWith (jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16) at HTMLDocument.A (jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16)

I tried to go in my AJAX webpage and I got this:

> Warning: ssh2_scp_recv() [function.ssh2-scp-recv]: Unable to receive remote file in
>       D:\www\SAGAPEC\application\modules\supervision\controllers\AdminController.php
>       on line 383 {"status":"OK","message":"LE ficheir a bien ete telecharger"}

Comment: "does not work" is no description. [ask] What do you observe? Server's and browser's error logs.

Answer (score 1):

> $(...).on is not a function
>
> jquery-1.5.1.min.js

The `on` method was introduced in jQuery 1.7.

Your version of jQuery is simply too old. It is from 2011!

Upgrade to a newer version of jQuery.

Note that all 1.x and 2.x versions of jQuery are past end of life and no longer receive security updates.

Use jQuery 3.3.